Collections of axioms that imply monotonicity?
I am currently searching for collections of axioms that imply monotonicity.
Let $N$ be a finite set of players, let $A$ be a finite set of alternatives, let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all linear order profiles on $A$, and let $F:\mathcal{P}\to 2^A\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ be a social choice correspondence.
Given any player $i\in N$, any alternative $x\in A$ and any linear order profile $P\in\mathcal{P}$, let $L_i(x,P)=\{y\in A\mid xP_iy\}$ be player $i$'s lower contour set at $x$.
A social choice rule $F:\mathcal{P}^N\to 2^A\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ is monotonic if and only if for all alternatives $x\in A$ and all linear order profiles $P,P'\in\mathcal{P}$, the following is true: if $x\in F(P)$ and $L_i(x,P)\subseteq L_i(x,P')$ for all $i\in N$, then $x\in F(P')$.
I am looking for collections of axioms that, once combined, imply monotonicity. Do you know any?

Being decisive (single-valued) and strategy-proof works.

Thank you for your comment. I suspect this comes from the fact that decisivenes and strategy-proofness, together with the unrestricted preference domain; imply dictatorship, which is obviously monotonic. Any other one that comes to mind, involving perhaps some form of IIA?

To get to dictatorship, you need to also assume that there are at least three alternatives and that every alternative can be elected. It is generally true that monotonicity and strategy-proofness are equivalent on a full domain for social choice-functions.

Thank you again for your comment—I didn’t know the equivalence holds so generally. Given the relationship between IIA and strategy-proofness found by Satterthwaite (1975), I’m kinda surprised there’s no known collection of axioms containing some form of IIA that together imply monotonicity.
